# laravel save many to many polymorphic

Tags: laravel, many-to-many

hi i want to save many to many polymorphic

in my case i want to save tag for book-review

it save tag but it save something more than tag

```
85  App\Models\Book_Review  132 1   2018-11-25 14:42:20 2018-11-25 14:42:20
86  App\Models\Book_Review  132 85      
87  App\Models\Book_Review  132 2   2018-11-25 14:42:22 2018-11-25 14:42:22
88  App\Models\Book_Review  132 87      
89  App\Models\Book_Review  132 3   2018-11-25 14:42:23 2018-11-25 14:42:23
90  App\Models\Book_Review  132 89
```

it save the tag and between every tag it save an object of taggable table with tag id of previous taggable object

this is my tag model relation

```
public function books_review()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany(Book_Review::class, 'taggable');
}
```

and this is my book-review model relation

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->morphToMany(Tag::class, 'taggable');
}
```

and this the part that i save tag in my controller

```
    foreach ($request->tagid as $item) {


        $book_review_tag = new Taggable();
        $taggable_id = strval($book_review->id);
        $book_review_tag->taggable_type = $this->Model;
        $book_review_tag->taggable_id = $taggable_id;

        $book_review_tag->tag_id = $item;
        $book_review->tags()->saveMany([$book_review_tag]);

    }
```

i use debugger and show me that it get id as a parameter when it goes back to the first of the for loop
and yet i don't know how to fix it

Comment: i can't get why it saves id